# Sanitize phone number with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a component that is outputing a phone number with this format:

`+1 (234) 567 - 8900`

And I need this format:

`2345678900`

so target the inital `+1`  and then all brackets, dashes and spaces so I can perform a `str.replace(regex, "")`.

What would be the regular expression to achieve this?

Until now I achieved with this expression:

`/[\s()-]+/g`

selecting everything but the initial `+1`.

[image]

I could add the `+` sign to the square bracket, but not the`1` since I only want to target the first occurrence

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would consider just using two expressions here, the first `^\+\d+\b` and the second `[^0-9]`. So basically take the leading + sign plus digit(s) off, and then remove any other non-numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Mako212, Actually at the moment I'm striping the `+1 ` with a str.replace("+1 ", ""), and then the expression above. But I'd like to achieve everything with one expression. Is there a way to put those two you provided in one?
Edit: remember that I don't want the `1` digit from the `+1` prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^\+1|[^0-9]+
```

You need to replace the found matches with an empty string. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8x9GL1/1).

*Details*:

- `^\+1` - `+1` at the start of string
- `|` - or
- `[^0-9]+` - one or more chars other than digits.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const regex = /^\+1|[^0-9]+/g;
const text = '+1 (234) 567 - 8900';
console.log(text.replace(regex, ''));
```